# Flutter Provider hook to close Streams?

Tags: flutter

I'm currently checking out the Flutter Provider package. I just want to expose some streams to widgets so I can listen to them. Something like this:

```
class OtherBloc {
  BehaviorSubject<String> sub = new BehaviorSubject();

  OtherBloc() {
    sub.add('my value');
  }

  add(String value) {
    sub.add(value);
  }
}
```

And then use it like this

```
class CounterPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final OtherBloc otherBloc = Provider.of<OtherBloc>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      body: new Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              StreamBuilder<Object>(
                stream: otherBloc.sub,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return Text(snapshot.data);
                }
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('____'),
                onPressed: () => {
                  otherBloc.add('lol')
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So I would provide it like this

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<OtherBloc>.value(
      value: OtherBloc(),
      child: MaterialApp(home: CounterPage()),
    );
  }
}
```

How ever now my `BehaivorSubject` is never `close()`'d. How can I call a dispatch type of hook so I can close my streams from a bloc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which Provider you are using but, 
You can use the dispose property of this [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).

In your case will be:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Provider<OtherBloc>.value(
          builder: (context) => OtherBloc(),
          dispose: (_, otherBloc) => otherBloc.dispose(),
          child: MaterialApp(home: CounterPage()),
       );
    }
 }
```